# Need a suggestion for buying new laptop

Tags: laptop, ssd

I am planning to buy new laptop. Need some suggestions from you guys.

Here is some details:

1. Can be used for multi - tasking (open several words file, excel, pdf, google meet at same time) without lagging
2. use SSD with capacity 256 GB or more
3. I plan to use video editing software like camtasia and playing game like Minecraft
4. Budget: if possible, around $700. If not, around $1000
5. My preference is towards ASUS but I am willing to consider other brands
6. Most of the time I will use it at workplace so portable laptop is not really my top priority (but I am open to that option as long it meets criteria 1 to 4)
7. Screen size maybe around 14 - 15 inch
8. Since I don't really need to travel a lot, for battery life maybe only need a decent one, around 2 - 4 hours
9. OS: windows

Other information (not sure it is helpful): I am using ASUS Vivobook A442U right now

Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most popular laptop on hardware.info meets all your requirements, except screen size. Its the [Lenovo IdeaPad 3 (82KU00CKMH)](https://nl.hardware.info/laptops.18/lenovo-ideapad-3-82ku00ckmh.602904) (link is in dutch)

Multitasking: You need enough cpu cores for this, and a ryzen 7 just has that. You also need 16GB of RAM, and this laptop also has that

Storage: The NVMe SSD (fast ssd) is 512 GB

Simple gaming and video editing: That CPU can handle it at once if needed :) and the Vega 8 is good enough for Minecraft at 60FPS.

Budget: Currently for sale for 650 euro's, which is about 750$ US

Brand: Sorry, ASUS didn't have much in the 10 most popular laptops...

Portability, probably better than my laptop, which is pretty portable

Screen size: a little over 15 inch

Battery life: In the hardest HWI test, it lasted 217 minutes, which is about 3 and a half hours

OS: Windows comes preinstalled, but if you don't like windows, you can use a different one (POP OS is my favorite)